# Prove that $S(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a vector subspace of size $2\times2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem statement:

*Be $M(2,\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices with real coefficients. Remember that square matrix $A$ is symmetric if $A^{t}=A$, and it is denoted by*

$$S(2,\mathbb{R})=\{A \in M(2,\mathbb{R})\ |\ A^{t} = A\}$$

*This is set of symmetric matrices of size $2\times2$.*

Now I need to prove that $S(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a vector subspace of $M(2,\mathbb{R})$.

What I have done is this to prove it:

**1.) Additive property:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
b & a
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
r & s\\ 
s & r
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
(a+r) & (b+s)\\ 
(b+s) & (a+r)
\end{bmatrix}$$

The addition of symmetric matrices give as a result another symmetric matrix.

**2.) Scalar multiplication property:**

$$\alpha \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
b & a
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha a & \alpha b\\ 
\alpha b & \alpha a
\end{bmatrix}$$

So the scalar multiplication of each matrix $a[_{i,j}]$ component does not affect its symmetry.

Is it my proof correct?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The proof looks right to me...

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks fine. Here is another take.

The map $A \mapsto A^t$ is a linear transformation $T: M(2,\mathbb{R}) \to M(2,\mathbb{R})$.

$S(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of fixed points of $T$ and so is a subspace, since it is $\ker (T-I)$.